# Trying to connect two or more UDP sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I am writing a very simple app, which needs to use many UDP sockets. But when I use to connect two or more sockets with adresses I get connect error: Connection refused. When I use it with one SOCK_STREAM(necessary for parent) and one datagram socket(for children) it works great, but after adding one more child which needs to use datagram socket I get this error.

Some pieces of source:

```
int openSocketByPath(char path[106], int type)
{
    char _path[108]="";
    struct sockaddr_un tempadres = {0};
    int tmpsock;
    tmpsock = socket(AF_UNIX, type, 0);
    if(tmpsock<0)
    {
        perror("socket() error");
        exit(2);
    }
    tempadres.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
    strcat(_path,path);
    strcpy(tempadres.sun_path+1,_path);
    tempadres.sun_path[0]=0;
    if((connect(tmpsock, (struct sockaddr *)&tempadres,sizeof(tempadres)))<0)
    {
        perror("connect() error");
        exit(3);
    }
    return tmpsock;
}
```

This creates sockets(first one for parents, loop for children):

```
sd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sd<0)
{
    perror("socket() error");
    exit(2);
}
on_exit(_close,NULL);
serveradres.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
strcpy(serveradres.sun_path,adres);
if((connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveradres,sizeof(serveradres)))<0)
{
    perror("connect() error");
    exit(3);
}
sprintf(id_work,"%d|%s",workers, id);
if(send(sd, id_work, sizeof(id_work), 0)<0) // wyslanie ID
{
    perror("send() error");
    exit(4);
}
if(recv(sd,&result,sizeof(result),0)<0)
{
    perror("recv() error");
    exit(5);
}
if(result==-1)
{
    printf("error while creating socket");
    exit(6);
}
sd = openSocketByPath(id, SOCK_STREAM);
for(int i=0; i<workers; i++)
{
    strcpy(tmp,"");
    sprintf(tmp,"%s%d",id,i);

    if(send(sd, tmp, sizeof(tmp), 0)<0) // wyslanie numeru pracownika
    {
        perror("send() error");
        exit(4);
    }
    if(recv(sd,&result,sizeof(result),0)<0)
    {
        perror("recv() error");
        exit(5);
    }
    if(result==-1)
    {
        printf("error while creating socket");
        exit(6);
    }
    workersSockets[i]=openSocketByPath(tmp,SOCK_DGRAM);
```

Comment: Why do you think you need multiple UDP sockets?

Comment: You *do* know that UDP sockets are generally *connectionless*, meaning one doesn't normally `connect` using such sockets? Instead one uses `sendto` and `recvfrom`.

Comment: Also, the error you get (I assume) is `ECONNREFUSED` which simply means no one is listening for connections on the address you provide.